# Dictionary on my Mac never adds words, even when I tell it to "learn" when I'm spell-checking

Tags: dictionary, spellcheck

Adding to the dictionary is not working for any app on my computer (word, messages, mail, etc.), and it hasn't through several OS upgrades, since I don't know when (we're on El Capitan now).  This has been true for all of the Mac users in our office.

It's not a matter of needing to know how.  We know how, it's just not working.  What could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you saying if you wipe a Mac, install totally fresh os and open TextEdit and add a few words to spellcheck, that fails? If not, it might be how your office is customizing the setup. This is an easy thing to check out of the box.

Comment: Maybe your local dictionary is not alphabetically sorted - see this link: https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-bulk-add-words-to-your-macs-spell-check-dictionary--mac-60820 for suggestion what to do in such case